# remove parameters from request URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am submitting a large form. It has many fields with unspecified values, which translate to `field=&field2=&field3...`.

I don't want these in the GET url. Only keep fields with non-empty value.

I figured out a way to do it with jquery:

```
$('#form').live('submit', function() {
    $('input[value=""]', '#form').remove();
});
```

which I thought would do exactly what I wanted.

But apparently I am missing something, because this selects and removes `input`s with entered text as well, not just the empty ones.

The above selector (before `remove()`) contains
`<input type=​"text" class=​"input-medium" name=​"field1" id=​"field1" value>​`, so it looks as if there is no value set. There is a value set though, as confirmed by
`$('input[name="field1"]').val()`, which correctly returns the text that is also visible on screen.

What's up with that? Any ideas?

---

Using jquery 1.7.2, Chrome 18.0.1025.168.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use [filtering](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) of fields, since `[value=""]` selector checks the default states of the inputs.

```
$('#form').on('submit', function() {
    $(':input', this).filter(function() {
        return this.value.length == 0;
    }).remove();
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/bCskH/

**UPDATE:** In order not removing input fields you can simply disable them:

```
$('#form').on('submit', function() {
    $(':input', this).filter(function() {
        return this.value.length == 0;
    }).prop('disabled', true);
});​
```

The effect will be the same, however IMHO much nicer :)

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/bCskH/1/

Comment: the `prop()` effect is indeed better than `remove()`, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery selector and `serialize()` to select only input that has value
here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/EypCH/1/)

```
<form id="test">
    <input name="field1" value="Test"><br/>
    <input name="field2" value=""><br/>
    <input name="field3" value="value"><br/>
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="submit"/>
</form>​


$('#btn').on('click',function() {
    alert($('#test input[value != ""]').serialize());
});​
```

also I doubt, `.live()` will work in jquery 1.7 use `.on()` instead. See this [link](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and it says it has been deprecated

Answer (score 1):

`[value=".."]` accesses the attribute which is not synced with the current value. Besides that, you cannot specify a selector as context - so move `#form` into the main selector and use `.filter()` to restrict the matched elements to empty ones:

```
$('#form input').filter(function() {
    return !$(this).val();
});
```